# What is the leadChangeEvent object?

Tags: object

I've Googled this and found literally no documentation. What is the function of the leadChangeEvent object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's part of the [Change Data Capture](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_intro.htm) feature. sObjects postfixed with `Event` on the name of some other sObject are the entities that represent change events as received by [Async Apex triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_subscribe_apex_triggers.htm) running on the platform, e.g.,

```
trigger LeadChangeEventTrigger on LeadChangeEvent (after insert) {

}
```

For standard objects, the name is `<object>ChangeEvent` (e.g., `LeadChangeEvent`); for custom objects, it is `<object>__ChangeEvent`, e.g., `MyObject__ChangeEvent` for some `MyObject__c`.